# Trying to make an auto purge/delete event discord.py

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.channel.get_channel(763827099084521484):
      await asyncio.sleep(5)
      await message.delete()
```

Though I get the error:

```py
  File “main.py”, line 24, in on_message
    if message.channel.get_channel(763827099084521484):
AttributeError: ‘TextChannel’ object has no attribute ‘get_channel’
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include code and errors as text not as an image.

Comment: `if message.channel.id == 763827099084521484`. You want to compare the `message.channel` with the ID and if that is `True` you do whatever you want to. `get_channel` is mostly used if you want to send something into a specific channel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good solution to the question:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.channel.id == 763827099084521484:
      await asyncio.sleep(5)
      await message.delete()
```

(Credit to Dominik)

Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow :D